# fuse4x sshfs on macosx execution error

Tags: macos, fuse, sshfs

I'm using sshfs on macosx 10.7 in my every day job.

To install sshfs I have used macport: "port install fuse4x sshfs".

The todays error:

```
$ sshfs user@domain.com:/path myfolder
fuse4x client library version is incompatible with the kernel extension (kext='0.9.0', library='0.9.2').
```

Any tips welcomed. I don't understand, I have not updated the system.

Comment: This isn't a question for stackoverflow, it should be moved to superuser or a more appropriate site of the network.

Answer (score 11):

Follow

```
$ brew info fuse4x-kext
```

instructions:

> In order for FUSE-based filesystems to work, the fuse4x kernel
>   extension must be installed by the root user:

```
$ sudo /bin/cp -rfX /usr/local/Cellar/fuse4x-kext/0.9.2/Library/Extensions/fuse4x.kext /Library/Extensions
$ sudo chmod +s /Library/Extensions/fuse4x.kext/Support/load_fuse4x
```

> If upgrading from a previous version of Fuse4x, the old kernel
>   extension will need to be unloaded before performing the steps listed
>   above. First, check that no FUSE-based filesystems are running:

```
$ mount -t fuse4x
```

> Unmount all FUSE filesystems and then unload the kernel extension:

```
$ sudo kextunload -b org.fuse4x.kext.fuse4x
```

Comment: you're not answering the actual OP question, that is macports' specific

Comment: the OP has a problem installing fuse on OSX. He tells what he received an error and wants a fix. This answer gives the fix. The question is not macports specific.

Comment: Hmm...I just installed sshfs with brew, run the sudo commands and then tested last line but `Kext org.fuse4x.kext.fuse4x not found for unload request.
Failed to unload org.fuse4x.kext.fuse4x - (libkern/kext) not found.`, ideas? Despite the err, the sshfs started to work -- SUPERB! Big THank you! +1

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr:**

try to manually update fuse4x-kect after updating the ports' tree using *sync* verb

```
port sync
port upgrade fuse4x-kext
```

**Longer read**

The error you pasted means that somehow macports didn't update the kext port fuse4x-kext when it upgraded fuse4x, it should have. I doubt your issue is still actual, since you're likely to have updated since october 2012, you should perform regular ports' upgrades and check when a new macports version is out in order to run a *selfupdate* verb.

As future reference you can guess what the kext port for a port is by looking at its information

```
port info fuse4x
```

or list of dependencies:

```
port deps fuse4x
```

Ports offering kexts can be loaded and unloaded from kernel by using *load* and *unload* verb.